# VS 2013 C# RDLC report can't access objects in Class

Tags: c#, oop, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

Basically I'm using a Class Buissness Object as a DataSet.

I have a Class Called Parent which contains an object Child.

Class Parent

```
class Parent
{
    private Child _ObjChild
    Public Child ObjChild { get { return this._ObjChild; } }

    public Parent(Child child) 
    {
        this._ObjChild = child;
    }
}
```

Class Child

```
class Child
{
    private string _Name;
    private int _Age;

    Public string Name { get { return this._Name; } }
    Public string Age { get { return this._Age; } }

    public Parent(string name, int age)
    {
        this._Name = name;
        this._Age = age;
    }
}
```

Now On the rdlc report, I've created a new DataSet of type Object and refer it to my Object of Parent.

Here is how I load my report :

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();

// This creates a new list of Parent() and returns it
bs.DataSource = this.CurrentReportView.GetData();
rds.Name = "dsMain";
rds.Value = bs;

this.rvMain.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

// This Returns the path where the report is residing
this.rvMain.LocalReport.ReportPath = this.CurrentReportView.GetReportFilePath();

this.rvMain.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);  
this.rvMain.RefreshReport();
```

Everything is working properly, except when I want to show my ObjChild it prints me an **#Error** I'am trying to get access to the properties Age or Name of my ObjChild but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a long search, I couldn't found the solution to fetch the data of the Child Object, but I've found a way around.

All I did was Exposed my Child Objects property into another call called ChildProperties.

```
class ChildProperties
{
    private Parent _ObjParent;

    // Exposing the Parent (if needed) and Child properties
    public string Name{ get { return this._ObjParent.ObjChild.Name; } }
    public intAge { get { return this._ObjParent.ObjChild.Age; } }

    public Parent(Parent parent) 
    {
        this._ObjParent = parent;
    }
}
```

Then I create a new DataSet of Object with this new class with the properties needed exposed.